# Can't change command text in a query (Excel VBA)

Tags: sql, vba, excel, odbc

So, down below you see my code, it's a bit modified version of a code I found here, can't find the source now...

The error I get is Run-time 1004, and I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

It works if I use variables up to strVal3 (See .CommandText line).

Any help/suggestions are highly appreciated.

```
Sub valandinai()

Dim strVal1 As String
Dim strVal2 As String
Dim strVal3 As String
Dim strVal4 As String
Dim strVal5 As String

Dim strSQL As String

'assume the list of values you want in the IN() statement in the sql is held in cells A1:A100 of sheet "MyValues" (obviously amend as appropriate)
'create the delimited list of values from sheet myValues and range A1:A100:

strVal1 = "('" & Join(Application.Transpose(Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A1:A999").Value), "','") & "')"
strVal2 = vbNewLine & "or kl.klnt_im_kodas in ('" & Join(Application.Transpose(Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A1000:A1999").Value), "','") & "')"
strVal3 = vbNewLine & "or kl.klnt_im_kodas in ('" & Join(Application.Transpose(Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A2000:A2500").Value), "','") & "')"
strVal4 = vbNewLine & "or kl.klnt_im_kodas in ('" & Join(Application.Transpose(Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A2501:A2999").Value), "','") & "')"
strVal5 = vbNewLine & "or kl.klnt_im_kodas in ('" & Join(Application.Transpose(Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A3000:A3500").Value), "','") & "')"
strVal6 = vbNewLine & "or kl.klnt_im_kodas in ('" & Join(Application.Transpose(Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A3000:A3500").Value), "','") & "')"
strVal7 = vbNewLine & "or kl.klnt_im_kodas in ('" & Join(Application.Transpose(Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A3501:A3999").Value), "','") & "')"
strVal8 = vbNewLine & "or kl.klnt_im_kodas in ('" & Join(Application.Transpose(Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A4000:A4411").Value), "','") & "')"

'============             IMPORTANT          =============================
'note that if you had a horizontal list of values, you need to use Application.Transpose twice:
'strVal = "'" & Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Sheets("MyValues").Range("A1:A100").Value)), "','") & "'"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("h1").Value = strVal1
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("h2").Value = strVal2
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("h3").Value = strVal3
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("h4").Value = strVal4
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("h5").Value = strVal5


'this is your current SQL statement as a string and we insert the values at the 'strVal' placeholder:

strSQL = "Select kl.klnt_im_kodas, Kl.Klnt_Pavadinimas, Su.Str_Id, Su.Str_Numeris," & vbNewLine & _
"--Ob.Obj_Id," & vbNewLine & _
"ob.obj_nr," & vbNewLine & _
"ob.obj_adresas," & vbNewLine & _
"Trim(To_Char(Vs.Ovs_ltu_Laikas, 'YYYY mm')) As menuo ," & vbNewLine & _
"Trim(To_Char(Vs.Ovs_ltu_Laikas, 'YYYY mm dd'))As Laikas ," & vbNewLine & _
"To_Char(Vs.Ovs_ltu_Laikas, 'D') As Sav_diena," & vbNewLine & _
"Trim(To_Char(Vs.Ovs_ltu_Laikas, 'hh24:mi'))As Valanda," & vbNewLine & _
"Vs.ovs_kiekis" & vbNewLine & _
"From Eta_Obj_Val_Suvart Vs" & vbNewLine & _
"Left Join Eta_Objektai Ob On Vs.Ovs_Obj_Id=Ob.Obj_Id" & vbNewLine & _
"Left Join Eta_Sutartys Su On Ob.Obj_Str_Id=Su.Str_Id" & vbNewLine & _
"left join eta_klientai kl on su.str_klnt_id=kl.klnt_id" & vbNewLine & _
"Where 1 = 1" & vbNewLine & _
"--And Vs.Ovs_Laikas>='2015.10.01'" & vbNewLine & _
"And Vs.Ovs_ltu_Laikas>=Add_Months(Trunc(Sysdate,'MM'),-12)" & vbNewLine & _
"and kl.klnt_im_kodas in" & vbNewLine

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = strVal1
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = strSQL

' Now use the strSQL in connection info (do NOT use the Array function to assign it though):
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection").ODBCConnection
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .CommandText = strSQL & strVal1 & strVal2 & strVal3 & strVal4 & strVal5
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .Connection = "connection string"
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .SavePassword = True
        .SourceConnectionFile = ""
        '.SourceDataFile = ""
        .ServerCredentialsMethod = xlCredentialsMethodIntegrated
        .AlwaysUseConnectionFile = False
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection").Delete
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection1")
        .Name = "Connection"
        .Description = ""
    End With
    'ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection").Refresh

    MsgBox "Done", vbInformation, "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: is strVal6  a dupe for A3000:A3500?  It may be too long, try just 4,5,6 https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/50819/too-long-sql-in-excel-vba.html

Comment: Can you place on line 56 of your code `MsgBox Len(strSQL & strVal1 & strVal2 & strVal3 & strVal4 & strVal5)` and review the query string length? As per @Nathan_Sav 's link provided query string length limit is 32767 characters.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! However, I did a more straightforward solution, I just added another joined one more table from the DB and added a variable in that table by which I could query the data without using the client ID.